# How to parametrize number of threads in JMeter 5.2.1

Tags: jmeter

I have a JMeter 5.2.1 project where in the SetUp thread I generate properties with names like `ThreadGroupName1-NumberOfThreads`, `ThreadGroupName2-NumberOfThreads`, etc. with values representing integers.

Now, I wish to access these properties in thread groups named `ThreadGroupName1`, `ThreadGroupName2`, etc. to parametrize the number of threads. I tried something like `${__jexl3(props.get(threadName + "-NumberOfThreads"))}` but it fails as `threadName` evaluates to `standardjmeterengine`.

Also, I tried to use `ctx` but `ctx.getThread()` and `ctx.getThreadGroup()` but they evaluate to `null`.

So far what 'works' for me is `${__jexl3(props.get("ThreadGroupName1-NumberOfThreads"))}` but I want it be parametrized by the name of the thread group.

Is it possible to do this?

Is this `threadName` returning `standardjmeterengine` a bug?

Update: In fact, the easiest 'solution' that provides the parametrized number of threads there is `${__P(ThreadGroupName1-NumberOfThreads)}` and what I want is to generate this key `ThreadGroupName1-NumberOfThreads` to be something like `${MyCurrentGroupName}-NumberOfThreads`, effectively providing a way to have an abstract method like

```
int GetNumberOfThreads(string threadGroupName)
{
  return properties.get(threadGroupName + "-NumberOfThreads";
}
```

Similarly, I wish to use this patter in Constant Throughput Timer as well with another prefix like `-Rpm`.

Comment: Did you tried my solution?

Comment: @user7294900, yes, thank you, but it does not work or I cannot understand, I think. I will update the question to be more clear.

Comment: @user7294900, I got your idea. I want the current Thread Group name; relaying on an index would be cumbersome. Anyway, ```ctx.getThreadNum()``` returns 0. I think ```ctx``` is not created yet when I try to use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can use any [JMeter Function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html) in the "Number of Threads" field of the [Thread Group](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Thread_Group) so this is not something you can do via UI. If you believe this is something everyone needs you can consider raising an [enhancement request](https://jmeter.apache.org/issues.html)

As a workaround you can

1. Set the number of threads to 1
2. Add [If Controller](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/six-tips-for-jmeter-if-controller-usage/) to the Thread Group and use the following [__groovy() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__groovy) as the condition:

   ```
   ${__groovy(ctx.getThreadNum() == 0 && vars.getIteration() == 1,)}
   ```
3. Add [JSR223 Sampler](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Sampler) as a child of the If Controller and put the following code into "Script" area:

   ```
   SampleResult.setIgnore()
   2.upto(props.get(ctx.getThreadGroup().getName() + '-NumberOfThreads') as int, { ctx.getThreadGroup().addNewThread(0, ctx.getEngine()) })
   ```

This way each thread Group will normally start with 1 thread, however this thread will read the property you defined earlier and add as many threads as needed.

Comment: Thank you, I think it must work so I accept your answer. But because I need to add elements to each group, I rather think it will be overkill for me. I will just use directly the values. I will add an enhancement request.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [JMeterContext](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/threads/JMeterContext.html#getThreadNum--)'s `getThreadNum` to get thread number (increment, because it starts with 0)

```
${__jexl3(props.get("ThreadGroupName"))}${__jexl3((ctx.getThreadNum()+1) + "-NumberOfThreads" )}
```